# Embedding ssl secured page: browser warning

Tags: browser, ssl, ssl-certificate

I want to load an ssl secured page from a different domain (payment provider) into an iframe. As far as I know some (or all?) browsers would warn the user if parts of a page are secured and other not.

- Is that true?
- If so, would the user get a warning if the main site would also be secured (but with another owner of the certificate)?
- Or could it be a problem when the domains have a different strength of their ssl key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll get a warning if a resource (e.g. a page) is delivered over HTTPS but it pulls in a resource (e.g. a script or frame) over HTTP.

Read this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/06/23/internet-explorer-9-security-part-4-protecting-consumers-from-malicious-mixed-content.aspx

Differing certificate owner and cipher strength do not trigger warnings.

Comment: Ah okay. So if I embed a https page into an iframe of an http site I wouldn't get a warning in any browser?